# Hide Fragment inside framelayout in android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

I got stuck with a small issue as i have shown my fragment inside framelayout without any problem but when i trying to hide fragment, it doesn't get hide and remain shown in my layout.

here what i have done :

```
Fragment fragment = new FooterClass();      
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
```

To SHOW Fragment

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_in, R.anim.slide_left_out).show(fragment).replace(R.id.footer_layout, fragment).commit();
```

To HIDE Fragment

```
ft.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.slide_left_out, R.anim.slide_left_in).hide(fragment).commit();
```

It is Showing Perfectly but not hiding do help me out

Comment: Does it work if you remove the custom animations, specifically when hiding?

Comment: Can you post your code that performs the fragment transaction? Specifically are you `add()`ing the fragment, or `replace()`ing it?